# Android application that display the notification for any application start or Stop. I want code for it

Tags: android

My code for broadcast Recevier

```
BroadcastReceiver Allapp = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS)){
            Log.i("appName", "Changes in Applications");
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi below is sample code for getting the Application which has been started(user is using)

ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List RunningTask = am
                    .getRunningTasks(4);

```
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo br = RunningTask.get(1);
        ar.topActivity.toString();
                       classname = ar.topActivity.getClassName().toString();
             packagename = ar.topActivity.getPackageName().toString();
```

Put this code in the to TimesTask and you will get the package name and class name which is used by the user.

ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo br = RunningTask.get(1);
will give you the task which has been stoped or went to back ground.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, what you want is not supported in Android.